# iPhone screen periodically unresponsive

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 6 had a problem where the screen stops responding to touch for a period of time. It always becomes responsive again after a while, although sometimes it requires a power button cycling.

For reasons I cannot explain, I feel this is a software issue. It happens in all apps, but it seems to have a sort of schedule.

Has anyone else an anything like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This advise is only meant for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6plus. ONLY.

If you experience problems with your screen being unresponsive, you may suffer from a design flaw of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus that is described [here](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/nz79qw/iphone-6-plus-touch-disease-touch-ic-engineering-flaw).

So this means your phone is probably broken and has to be replaced eventually. But you can try the following for the time being.

This worked for my phone:

Apply some some light pressure to the case as you would pretend to twist or bend your phone. Only apply light pressure. **Don't really bend it though.** Just apply some pressure and check if the display is reacting again. It worked in my case. You will have to repeat this all the time it does not respond to touch.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely touch disease. They don't offer repairs for the iPhone 6 though, only 6+. For the 6 it's a normal repair, $350. That what I paid for the phone.

Answer (score 2):

No, not as a general issue across all apps.

Some apps such as for example Safari may be "slow to scroll" (for example web pages that have Javascript scroll handlers that do not declare themselves as never calling preventDefault() can be slow to scroll).

However, if you see this as a general problem across all apps, and you have to powercycle the phone - it sounds that a hardware problem is likely.

If the phone is still under warranty - take the issue to Apple Support. If it is not, you could still try Apple Support.

Comment: Ok, so, is this likely to be a problem *in* the screen itself? IE, if I replace the screen should it fix it? I'm not entirely sure how the touch electronics are arranged - does it all happen in the screen or is there additional hardware upsteam that might be an issue?

Comment: There's additional components. If you bend your iPhone 6, you could risk destroying the touch ICs, which would obviously create problems with touch recognition.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a touch IC, or is this logic embedded in some other chip? I ask because if it is part of another chip, then that suggests the problem is in the screen itself as nothing else seems broken.

Comment: Yes, there is such thing as a touch IC. In particular, on the iPhone 6 it is primarily the 343S0694 IC from Texas Instruments that handles touch.

Comment: Interesting. Ok well that makes things more difficult to test. I suppose I could put my display on my wife's 6 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If this has been happening ever since you have bought your phone, it may be a hardware problem with the touchscreen.

However, if has been happening recently, it may be because of the version of iOS that you are running. Make sure that you have updated to the latest stable or beta version of iOS. In addition, make sure that there are not too many background processes that are running.

Answer (score 0):

My phone acts like this immediately after doing a big operation like removing my iCloud Library or adding or removing an Exchange Email Account. I think the sheer amount of work the phone has to major deletes, uploads & downloads cause  the phone slow it down sometimes.